# NodeJs child_process working directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, working-directory

I am trying to [execute a child](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) process in a different directory then the one of its parent.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec(
    'pwd',
    {
        cdw: someDirectoryVariable
    },
    function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        // ...
    }
);
```

I'm doing the above (though of course running "pwd" is not what I want to do in the end). This will end up writing the pwd of the parent process to stdout, regardless of what value I provided to the cdw option.

What am I missing?

(I did make sure the path passed as cwd option actually exists)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

The option is short for *current working directory*, and is spelled `cwd`, not `cdw`.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('pwd', {
  cwd: '/home/user/directory'
}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  // work with result
});
```

Comment: Oh.. typo.. Now wondering how I did not spot that. Fixing the typo made the code work as expected.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  On windows 10, not sure if that matters

Comment: @Matt Westlake I know I'm probably late but I think on Windows you need to execute `cd` instead of `pwd` like so
`var cmd =  \`cd foo/bar ⏎
ls\`;  var exec =  require('child_process').exec; ...`

Comment: @Jeroen De Dauw lol, we've all been there

Comment: @vbtheory Worth noting that there's also no `ls` on Windows (it's `dir` instead) and directory separators are backslashes, not forward slashes.

Comment: can i enter the windows path "c:\\"? its not working for me

Answer (score 1):

If you're on windows you might choke on the path separators. You can get around that by using the `join` function from the built-in Node.js `path` module. Here is @hexacyanide's answer but with `execSync` and `join` instead of `exec` (which doesn't block the event loop, but not always a huge deal for scripts) and Unix file paths (which are cooler and better than Window file paths).

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const { join } = require('path');
execSync('pwd', { cwd: path.join('home', 'user', 'directory') });
```