# Change working directory for npm scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, makefile, package.json

**Q:** Is it possible to change the the context in which npm runs scripts?

What I want to is the following:

```js
"scripts": {
   "test": "gulp mocha",
   "pre-install": "./deps/2.7/cpython/configure --prefix=$(pwd)/build --exec-prefix=$(pwd)/build && make -C deps/2.7/cpython && make -C deps/2.7/cpython install",
   "install": "node-gyp rebuild"
},
```

Obviously `cd deps/2.7/cpython/ && ./configure` would work on UNIX-like systems but not on windows.

**Why:** The root of the problem is, that the `configure` command of the python repo outputs files into the directory where it is called. The files however are build relevant for `make` and `make install` which look for the files in the directory of the repo.

In this case I can't change the `Makefile` since the build process of Python is understandably complex.

**Alternative:** The alternative is probably to write some `install.js` and use node's OS independent API and some `child_process.exec()`, which I am probably gonna do. However, not leaving *npm* would be really nice.

Comment: I believe there is nothing wrong about writing an extra script and run that one from npm.

Comment: `cd deps/2.7/cpython/ && ./configure` should work on Windows - what problem do you encounter?

Comment: Several. You can't use `./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/somepath`. It's not pretty. I haven't found it yet, but `npm` is probably using `var spawn = require('child_process').spawn`, which would allow you to set options like `{cwd: pwd + 'somepath'}`, but isn't exposing it. 
It's philosophy as well: Package manage have loads of functionality that they have in common with build tools. If they go this road, they need to have certain features like this as well.

Comment: I've solved it with a fairly large `install.js `, which does roughly that and it gets called from `package.json` like above. The API of `child_process` isn't that easy to handle, though, since it throughs laods of hard to debug erros. Took me some time, but I am happy now

Comment: Authored a PR [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10957)

Comment: Could you add your answer as per the resolution here: https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/10958 ? This will help anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

`npm` allows only to do `cd dir && command -args`, which will also run on Windows.

A change to use `node`'s spawn functionality has been made in PR https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/10958, but was rejected, due to the above solution.

Comment: Not sure if I've done something, but have recently had this break in Windows.

Answer (score 8):

As noted above:

> npm is probably using

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
```

> which would allow you to set options like:

```
    {cwd: pwd + 'somepath'}
```

> but isn't exposing it.
>
> I've solved it with a fairly large `install.js`, which does roughly that and it gets called from `package.json` like above. The API of `child_process` isn't that easy to handle, though, since it throws loads of hard to debug errors. Took me some time, but I am happy now.

Comment: Rights. Unfortunately it has been rejected in PR as noted in my answer.

Comment: similar to :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894433/nodejs-child-process-working-directory  which works for me too

Comment: Which is why we all moved to using `yarn`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 const { execSync } = require('child_process');

 execSync(`cd ${your_working_directory} && npm install`)
```