# How to specify the path of `package.json` to npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I use `npm` scripts to build my project.  I'd like to be able to run the scripts from a different directory.  That is, instead of doing the following:

```
cd project;
npm run build;
cd ..
```

...I'd like to simply do something like:

```
npm run build -config project/package.json;
```

or

```
npm run build -wd project;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286498/change-working-directory-for-npm-scripts

Comment: I don t think it is possible as i have not found the related switch to tell npm the wd. But, i guess you could call your commands within a sub shell like this `cmd /C "cd C:\ && npm -v"` see more [here](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Using [`--prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#prefix) worked for me:

`npm --prefix /path/to/project run build`

Where `path/to/project` is the directory where your *package.json* with `build` command defined.

Comment: this mostly works for me, but I can't fine much documentation on `--prefix` is minimal.  I have a path like `/path/to-my-project/`, and it doesn't seem to be working.  the other npm dependencies are going into different project folders instead of the `node_modules` folder.  Is there a way to escape these arguments?  I tried single and double quotes...

Comment: This worked great in my "Pre-build" Visual Studio event. It's wierd that I didn't see `--prefix` option in NPM documentation.

Comment: `prefix` isn't an option but rather a config setting.  It's documented on the `npm-folders` page (https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders)

Comment: there are multiple package.*.json files to work with : how to specify which one?

Comment: scripts works but the package-lock.json file is created at the place where I execute the command. Can I avoid that too?

Answer (score 2):

to change the path of package.json that npm gets
this didnt work for me

```
npm --prefix /path/to/project run build
```

but this did

```
npm --prefix /path/to/project run
```

but this does not permanently change it
for example you can say

```
npm --prefix /path/to/project run test
```