# How can I replace brunch with webpack (2.x) in elixir phoenix (1.3.x)?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework, webpack-2

I try to replace brunch with webpack, so that I can develop with hot-module-replacement. Furthermore I would have access to more sophisticated build tools.

All Tutorials out there describe Phoenix 1.2.x and Webpack 1.x, where both of them are outdated.

Thanks for any advice and or clue

**Tech Stack**

- Elixir: 1.4.2
- Phoenix: 1.3.0-rc
- Brunch: 2.10.8

**Ressources**

already checked

- http://matthewlehner.net/using-webpack-with-phoenix-and-elixir/
- [How to specify the path of `package.json` to npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078968/how-to-specify-the-path-of-package-json-to-npm)
- https://medium.com/@roaltay/how-to-use-phoenix-react-webpack-5383fa556b62#.jxude7r47

Comment: It should not really depend on the version of `webpack`, so do it for phoenix 1.2 and migrate phoenix. Nobody will describe you here the whole process for the version that was released yesterday.

Comment: I will post the answer shorty and yes I got two responses alteady on elixir forum. cheers

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I don't describe the process because I would say that the links to posted already describes it very well.

But if you need some example and something ready to use check this https://github.com/yordis/phoenix_assets_webpack

It's actually using `phoenix 1.3` generator instead of `1.2`.
is **This repo meant to be modify per project**, normally contains the default setups for any project using `jquery` but it's very helpful for the starting point.

For React

- Remove `jquery` from `npm` as well as any present on the `webpack config`.
- Install `react` and `react-dom` using `npm install react react-dom --save`
- Modify the `entry` point file with the `react` code.

Comment: @radosch let me know if you have any question so I can update the answer with your concerns.