# Jenkins fails on build step 'npm i'

Tags: jenkins, npm, installation

I have a local Jenkins installed (under Windows 10 OS) and have an unexpected behavior.

**Suggestions why ?**

Step 1 is execuded properly :

> cd C:\MYFOLDER
>
> npm run config

But Step 2 fails (ERROR):

> cd C:\MYFOLDER
>
> npm i

The console output is:

```
npm ERR! path C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-clone-bc17270a\package.json
```

Note: There is a package.json in C:\MYFOLDER with the needed installs, but Jenkins looks for it in a completely another folder.

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: @saikat chakrabortty v7.5.0

Comment: you can try once by clearing cache, `npm cache clean`

Comment: @saikat chakrabortty same error

Answer (score 0):

Did you look here? [How to specify the path of `package.json` to npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078968/how-to-specify-the-path-of-package-json-to-npm) ...   specify your package.json. Your node installed in jenkins is going to its default package.json