# Tell npm to look for the package.json in a specific folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Let's for the sake of simplicity, say that I have a folder structure like so:

```
root
|-build
  |-package.json
|-src
  |-foo
    |-foo.csproj
    |-foo.cs
    |-bar.cs
    |-bin
      |-...
  |-foo.sln
```

Let us then say that I change the current directory to `root\src\foo\bin` and execute any `npm` command, say for example the `npm install` command like so:

```
C:\root\src\foo\bin> npm install
```

We will observe that **npm** will start looking for the `package.json` file within the *current directory*, and since it won't find it, will report an error like so:

```
npm ERR! path C:\root\src\foo\bin\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
1>  npm ERR! errno -4058
1>  npm ERR! syscall open
1>  npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\root\src\foo\bin\package.json'
1>  npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
1>  npm ERR! enoent
```

In this case, supposing I had a limitation that I *had* to execute all commands from within the `root\src\foo\bin\` folder, how would I tell **npm** to look for the `package.json` file that's in the `root\build\` folder?

Comment: `npm start --prefix 'path/to/your/package.json'`

Comment: Thank you. It appears as though you don't need the file name; just the folder name will do. Supplying the file name `package.json` will produce an error.

Comment: oh yeah, what I meant was the path to package.json file only. Anyways glad it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to ensure i understood your question right, you are in root directory and `package.json` is in build sub-directory and you want to install packages from root directory, right? if so

You can give `npm install <folder_path>` so in your case from root you can give `npm install build/`

Answer (score 0):

Athough [HelpingHand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648253/helping-hand) in the comments section to the question, and [pavan skipo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9907206/pavan-skipo) in the answers have provided the correct answers, I am writing this answer to consolidate what knowledge I have acquired about solving this issue as I got the answer to this question by [searching some more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40434116/303685) soon after having posted this question.

**To run the npm install command and specify a path to the package.json file:**

```
$ npm install <folder_path>

$ npm install "..\..\..\build\"
```

**To run any other npm command, for example an npm script and specify a path to the package.json file:**

```
$ npm --prefix <folder_path> run <script_name>
```

For e.g if the `package.json` had a script named `build`, the command would be:

```
$ npm --prefix "..\..\..\build" run build
```

Note that:

1. The trailing slash `\` (or `\`) after the folder name is optional. So `..\..\..\build\` is the same as `../../../build/`, which is the same as `..\..\..\build`.
2. `<folder_path>` is the path of the folder that contains the `package.json` that you want npm to look for.