# npm - run scripts in directory other than cwd

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a script which scaffolds an app. This involves making a new directory in the current directory inside which the app's scaffold files will be unpacked.

At the end of my script I run a series of npm/node commands as follows (`appDir` is a reference to the child dir created to host the app; it exists by the time these commands run):

```
const postInstCmds = [
    'cd '+appDir,
    'npm init -y',
    'npm install add-npm-scripts --save-dev',
    'npm install http-server --save-dev',
    'add-npm-scripts server "http-server"',
    'npm run server'
];
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
postInstCmds.forEach(cmd => execSync(cmd));
```

However it seems the first `cd` command is being ignored; the subsequent commands are being executed in the parent, not child, directory.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35802161/1352288), which explicitly says that npm supports `cd *` operations, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding something (I'm no npm wizard). I've also tried using npm's `--prefix` argument to specify path, but no joy.

---

[UPDATE]

The linked dup suggests `npm start <dir>` but this seems to work only if `<dir`> *already* contains a package.json. As per my sequence of commands, I want to move to the directory and *then* create the package.json (via `npm init`). Another answer there suggests `npm run --prefix`, but `run` again requires an extant pacakge.json, since it reads from the `scripts` object.

I have also tried `npm init --prefix <dir>` but the arg doesn't seem to be supported for `npm init`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get npm start at a different directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172442/how-can-i-get-npm-start-at-a-different-directory)

Comment: Thank you - I didn't find that during my searching. I will go read.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've updated my question after studying your linked dup. Thanks for any help you're able to offer.

Comment: Yes; the prefix has to point to a package directory. Also I believe every time you exec it starts again, so the cd doesn't "stick". But that's kind of an awkward way to approach it; why not copy a preset package file with the right script and dependency into  the directory, then prefix will work for install and run? What's the bigger context here?

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much the conclusion I've come to, too. I'll have my bin script create the package.json by writing the file manually to the directory. I was just trying to harness `npm init` but it doesn't seem like you can get that to happen in a non-cwd directory. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is running different child processes for each command. So the `cd` command runs in a subprocess and exits. Then the next command runs in a *new* subprocess that is in the original directory you started in and not in the directory that the `cd` command navigated to.

One fix would be to get rid fo the `cd` command and instead pass the directory as a `cwd` option for each `execSync()` call.

```
postInstCmds.forEach(cmd => execSync(cmd, {cwd: appDir}));
```