# How to run a shell script from an Electron app

Tags: shell, electron

I've built an Electron app that requires to run a shell script, any suggestions on how to achieve this? I believe I'll have to spawn a child process from Electron and then find the path to the shell script, but I don't really have a clear idea or example on how to do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you run it outside of Electron?

Comment: Hi there, from terminal, cd to directory and `./script`

Comment: Is your script written in such a way that you need to run it from that directory, and that you can't e.g. run `cd /tmp; /path/to/your/script` instead?

Comment: I need to be in that directory

Comment: Sounds like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894433/nodejs-child-process-working-directory) then