# How to execute command, from particular path in node js?

Tags: node.js

I want to execute my node command `execSync('DB_HOST=localhost DB_DATABASE=test_ver  DB_USERNAME=root DB_PASSWORD=Testing@123 PORT=5010 nodemon server.js ');` , from this path `/var/www/test/` , can anyone please help me how to do this ?   here i have added my whole function

```
commonService.exec_api = async function () {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve) {
        const execSync = require('child_process').exec;
       let child_process_obj = execSync('DB_HOST=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_HOST + ' DB_DATABASE=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_DATABASE + '  DB_USERNAME=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_USERNAME + ' DB_PASSWORD=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_PASSWORD + '  PORT=' + process.env.UNITTEST_API_BACKEND_PORT + ' nodemon server.js ');
        let unittest_api_backend_process_id = child_process_obj.pid;
        const sessionStorage = require('node-sessionstorage')
        sessionStorage.setItem("backend_pid", unittest_api_backend_process_id);
        resolve(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Did yo run this? Do you get any error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJs child\_process working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894433/nodejs-child-process-working-directory)

Comment: let child_process_obj = execSync('DB_HOST=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_HOST + ' DB_DATABASE=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_DATABASE + '  DB_USERNAME=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_USERNAME + ' DB_PASSWORD=' + process.env.UNITTEST_DB_PASSWORD + '  PORT=' + process.env.UNITTEST_API_BACKEND_PORT + ' nodemon server.js ', {
            cwd: '/var/www/vericurious/VeriCurious-AppServices/'
        });
        console.log(unittest_api_backend_process_id); , this is working but i am not getting its process id